# Send json as query body via rest call

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rest, graphql

I need to send request of json via rest, the code for the client (rest) is Node, and the code of the server is golang.

The body look like following

```
const query = "{\"query\":\"query {n  result: application(id: \"fb7b5992-4d0a-4782-acb7-13ae6cc66102\") {n    idn    namen    providerNamen    descriptionn    integrationSystemIDn    labelsn    status {n      conditionn      timestamptn    }}n}\"}"
```

When I run the code I got the following error from the server (go) 
and i use

This is the call

```
const app = await fetch(`https://eway-auth-oauth.kh.de-arch.sho.ca.k8s-han.znd.com/dir/graphql`, {
    method: 'post',
    body: queryBody,
    headers: {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'DNT': '1',
        'Origin': 'https://eway-auth.kh.devx-ar.znd.com',
        'authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'tenant': '3e6rezae-38b5-46a0-b1ed-9ccee153a0am'
    }
});
return {
    ky: await app.json(),
}
```

**ERROR**

```
json body could not be decoded: invalid character 'z' after object key:value pair
```

The `z` is the starting latter in the `application(id:z....`
it is a number which I need to send.

Any idea how could I overcome this? Im struggling with it two days

Btw,

when I try it the curl command it works, something when I copy the data from the terminal to js variable `query` makes the error, not sure way :(

**update**

This is the curl which **works for me** (and the code above doesnt...)

```
curl `https://eway-auth-oauth.kh.de-arch.sho.ca.k8s-han.znd.com/dir/graphql` \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'DNT: 1' \
-H 'Origin: https://eway-auth.kh.devx-ar.znd.com \
-H 'authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
-H 'tenant: 3e6rezae-38b5-46a0-b1ed-9ccee153a0am' \
--data-binary '{\”query\":\"query {\n  result: application(id: \"fb7b5992-4d0a-4782-acb7-13ae6cc66102\") {\n    id\n    name\n    providerName\n    description\n    integrationSystemID\n    labels\n    status {\n      condition\n      timestampt\n    \n}\n}\n}\"}'
 \
--compressed
```

Comment: Whats supposeed to be in queryBody

Comment: That's not json, but javascript or some string. That's why it's not working. The option part of your `fetch` method, that is json. + could you please format your body properly? It's hard to read currently.

Comment: You are stringifying a string?

Comment: Post the Go code if you need help with that. Otherwise, remove the Go tag.

Comment: the body, if its exactly like what you have given here, is toatlly invalid BS when compared to a valid JSON, also why do you need to stringify a string?? Did you intented to parse it instead?

Comment: @ehab - it should be some json data

Comment: @Paul - is it better now, if not let me know and i'll try to format it again

Comment: @NidhinDavid - I try many things to make it work, one of them is to `JSON.stringify` , which is not helping here , otherwise I got the error `nvalid character 'z'` any suggestion/ direction what to try ? im opend to every suggestion

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with that code on your backend site? Even if you make it to have a proper json format like `{ query: "your text properly encoded" }` the data within your body doesn't make any proper sense to me and probably won't help you on the backend. Where does that body come from? Why does the data look like this? Why is this no proper (escaped) object?

Comment: @Paul - this is some spec which we need to use, and working with `curl` , the exact same body in `js` (copeid from terminal) doesnt works, any idea ?

Comment: @NidhinDavid - Yes you write, I fix the json (its valid json) , it's just copy issue, do you something now ?

Comment: It's still no json. Learn about json e.g on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON:
But, your url tells me something about `graphql`, which uses an api which is a little json like - but even though no json - for retrieving data. For posting data it seems to use json though. Please take a deeper look at https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/ + Could you add the full (working) curl statement?

Comment: @Paul - I've added the curl command, please see my update

Comment: Try this: `const query = {"query":"query {\n  result: application(id: \"fb7b5992-4d0a-4782-acb7-13ae6cc66102\") {\n    id\n    name\n    providerName\n    description\n    integrationSystemID\n    labels\n    status {\n      condition\n      timestampt\n    \n}\n}\n}"}` This is at least proper escaped json. And `queryBody = JSON.stringify(query)`.

Comment: @Paul - thank you very much this is solved the issue! please provide it as answer :) Thanks again!

Comment: @NinaS Happy to hear that :) I added it as an answer with some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json is not properly escaped within your string representation of it. Especially it's necessary to escape the quotes within the values and to escape backslashes.
That means `" => \"` or, if already escaped, `\" => \\\"` and e.g. `\n => \\n`.

You can assign the json directly to the query. In that case your IDE is usually already complaining, if the json is not valid.

```
const query = {
  "query": "query {\n  result: application(id: \"fb7b5992-4d0a-4782-acb7-13ae6cc66102\") {\n    id\n    name\n    providerName\n    description\n    integrationSystemID\n    labels\n    status {\n      condition\n      timestampt\n    \n}\n}\n}"
};
```

You can also use `'` instead to avoid needing the escaping. In most scenarios this shouldn't make a difference. Even though I'm not sure of your parser on the backend side is fine with this.

```
const query = {
  "query": "query {\n  result: application(id: 'fb7b5992-4d0a-4782-acb7-13ae6cc66102') {\n    id\n    name\n    providerName\n    description\n    integrationSystemID\n    labels\n    status {\n      condition\n      timestampt\n    \n}\n}\n}"
};
```

Afterwards you need to pass it to your http request as a string:

```
const queryBody = JSON.stringify(query);
```